# Getting rid of duplicate controls when using PaneSelector and Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I'm using `PaneSelector` in my `Manipulate` controls to change the limits on a variable for 3 (or more) different selections. Here 2/3 of the controls are the same, while the other has a different range. How can I use `PaneSelector` (or similar) and eliminate duplicate controls?

```
Control[{{tab,1},{1->"func A",2->"func B",3->"func C"},Setter}],
PaneSelector[{
1->Control[{{maxrange,5},1,10}],
2->Control[{{maxrange,5},1,10}],
3->Control[{{maxrange,15},10,20}]
},Dynamic@tab]
```

Since the first two controls are exactly the same, is there a way to consolidate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PaneSelector[{1 -> Control[{{maxrange, 5}, 1, 10}], 3->Control[{{maxrange, 15}, 10, 20}]}, 
  Dynamic[tab /. 2 -> 1]]
```

or

```
PaneSelector[{## & @@ Thread[{1, 2} -> Control[{{maxrange, 5}, 1, 10}]], 
   3 -> Control[{{maxrange, 15}, 10, 20}]}, Dynamic@tab]
```